# How to convert this textarea input to this example in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i want to convert this textarea state to something which i shown down here

text area input

```js
function test() {
  const [test, settest] = useState(``);
  let text = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#homepage\:j_idt84\:bestMetroPrices\:0\:j_idt96\:1\:bestMetroPrice')
  print("Best Petrol Price in Perth today is:", elem.text)
  price = elem.text;
}
```

to this

```
function test() { \n    const [test, settest] = useState(``); \n    let text = `browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#homepage\:j_idt84\:bestMetroPrices\:0\:j_idt96\:1\:bestMetroPrice')\n    print("Best Petrol Price in Perth today is:", elem.text)\n    price = elem.text`;
```

the below code is just the same code above which is minified to one line with \n and blank spaces meaning indentation , how can we achieve this dynamically, can anyone try to help me with this

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package if you are using npm [minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify)

or
use [use this website](https://javascript-minifier.com/)